# Terminal Command Mac Alter table SQLite3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, sqlite, terminal

What is the terminal command, or where is a good resource to get them, to alter a table. And, do I need to re run the $rake db:migrate after I do this? I am running RoR on Snow Leopard. Last question, can I make an already created column non-null.

UPDATE: figured out how to alter, just need to know if I need to rake db:migrate after alter.

Comment: Change your question's title when you change the questions so totally and drastically!  And btw, one question per question (you have three here, though your title reflects but one -- the one you don't CARE about anymore!-) is much better Stack-Overflow behavior.

Comment: If you used Rails Migrations I answered the remaining question also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> good resource to get them, to alter a
>   table

Check these to get a grasp at how migrations work

[Rails Migrations Cheatsheet](http://dizzy.co.uk/ruby_on_rails/cheatsheets/rails-migrations)

[Railsguides: Migrations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html)

---

@run `rake db:migrate`: yes

---

@created to non-null: yes (Check `7.1 add_column` and `7.2 change_column` in the first link